# How to get the value of the @Size annotation, above the field of object

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, reflection, bean-validation, dto

I need to pull over the field the attribute value from the **@Size** annotation

```
private static int getMaxLimitSize(Field field){

    field.setAccessible(true);
    Size annotation = field.getAnnotation(Size.class);

    int zero = 0;

    if(annotation == null) return zero;

    return annotation.max();

}
```

here is the **@Size** constraint over the dto type object field

```
 @Size(message = "{validate.documentid.size}", max = 36)
private String documentId;
```

But when I try to get an annotation, I get **null**

```
Size annotation = null;
```

This annotation is above objects of type **dto** and is not processed, but when the **entity** is processed, then this annotation is visible ?!!!

using **Spring Boot**

the error **messages** are in the file - **ValidationMessages.propertie**s

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {



    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        source.setBasename("classpath:ValidationMessages");
        return source;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return validator;
    }

}
```

Here's what is passed in the method - **getMaxLimitSize()**, type Field

```
private static void processLimitValidateForField(Field field, Object object, List<Object> values){

    Class<?> type = field.getType();
    String typeName = type.getSimpleName();

    boolean isTypeClassOfString = isStringType(typeName);

    int limitString = 0;

    if(isTypeClassOfString){
        limitString = getMaxLimitSize(field);
        setValue(field, typeName, object, values, limitString);
    } else {
        setValue(field, typeName, object, values, limitString);
    }
}
```

Please explain why the dto object is not visible to the validator, or why reflection does not see the validate annotation and what can be done?

How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

you can get `field value` by calling the method `Field#get(currentObject)`

```
if (field.isAccessible()) {
    Object someValue = field.get(object);
}
```

Comment: And must I do with this?  I passed an object and I tried to get an object and I get null.

Comment: the `object` is who has the field which you wan to get its value JIC.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336387/why-does-validation-not-work-on-objects-of-type-dto-but-only-on-entities

Comment: ? what do you want to do?