# Why does validation not work on objects of type DTO, but only on entities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, bean-validation

I have an annotation set over objects of type **dto**, the same as over objects of type **Entity**. The annotation works on **entities**, but it does not work on objects of type **dto**.

I work in **SpringBoot**.
**application.properties**

```
validate.packageid.size = "The field 'PACKAGEID' can contain only {max} symbols.";
```

**config file**

```java
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        source.setBasename("classpath:ValidationMessages");
        return source;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return validator;
    }

}
```

**dto**

```java
@Size(message = "{validate.packageid.size}", max = 36)
private String documentId
```

**entity**

```java
@Column(name = "DOCUMENTID")
@Size(message = "{validate.packageid.size}", max = 36)
private String documentId;
```

I cannot use the annotation **@Valid** because I fill an object of **dto** type with reflection technology.

```java
public static  <S> S fillData (S object, List<Object> values){
    return obtainMetadataOfObject(object, values);
}
```

I need to be able to get the constraint annotation, or rather its parameters, set on the fields of the dto object (but in the case of the dto object I get null, since Spring may not know what to use the constraint annotations set on the fields of the dto object), in the case of entity - it turns out, but the entity validator is engaged by Spritg, since it manages the entity as a component from the Application context.

To validate the dto on the web client side, I use the **@Valid** annotation in the parameters of the method that handles the request from the client

For validation dto from

**Update**

I put the annotation **@Validation** over **dto** and after that I got the data I need.

It work for classes that don't have classes-heir.

I get data of annotation **@Size**

```java
    private static int getMaxLimitSize(Field field){

            field.setAccessible(true);

            Size annotation = field.getAnnotation(Size.class);

            int zero = 0;

            if(annotation == null) return zero;

            return annotation.max();

        }
```

But this **does not work** for objects whose fields are split into several classes : several abstract and one produce.

Validation does not work for composite objects of type **DTO**, Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Where are you validating it?

Comment: Question answered perhaps? Accepting it by klicking the green checkmark would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

The validation needs to be triggered somewhere, for entities in your case the spring framework does it (or jpa perhaps). DTOs never make it there. So you have to trigger the validation (`validator.validate`) on your own, as per the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bean-constraints.html#section-obtaining-validator). Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100317/spring-dto-validation-in-service-or-controller) asking at which application layer to do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 @PostMapping("/test")
    public void test( @RequestBody @Valid final UserDto dto) {

        // logic
    }
```

u should add @Valid annotation in controller.
If u want validate dto in service layers u should add @Validate and @Valid :

```
@Service
@Validated
public class Service {

   public void test(@Valid UserDto dto){
       // logic
   }
}
```